# React fetch API won't show any data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm making a provider in my react native mobile App and when I try to fetch an API and set the data into a state the responded data is undefined or null. I don't know what is going wrong. First it was working not anymore now.

Can someone tell my what is going wrong? Here is my code:

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const DataApiContext = React.createContext(null);

function DataApiProvider({children}) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://data.rivm.nl/covid-19/COVID-19_uitgevoerde_testen.json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(response => setData(response))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }, []);

  console.log(data)

  return (
    <DataApiContext.Provider value={{data}}>
      {children}
    </DataApiContext.Provider>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<DataApiProvider />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Are you sure there's a problem? I just ran this code and it worked. It took probably 30 seconds to load the data, but it did work.

Comment: Well for me it shows that data is still null

Comment: I've updated your question to be a running example. Aside from creating context and the console.log, it has remained unchanged. If you run it, and wait long enough, it does work (You may get a few dialogs about unresponsive pages, choose wait).

Comment: Oh yea I see data indead, but I don't know then what is going wrong inside my app. Because the data value keeps staying null when using setData(data) inside the fetch

Comment: To answer that I think we'll need more context. Is where are you seeing `null`? Is it a child of the `DataApiProvider` component?

Comment: Uhm, when I do console.log(data) from the useState data variable. It should be changed to the body of the api response. Well that was it first but not anymore. Now it still says null

Comment: I don't understand. The same console log in the question goes back to saying `null` at some point?

Comment: Yea that's right, the console.log in the question will say null. But when I try to access the data variable inside of another component it will show still the const [data, setData] = useState(null) so null

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the value object like a object.

```
<DataApiContext.Provider value={data}>
    {children}
</DataApiContext.Provider>
```